# Export specific PowerPoint slides to a single high-quality PDF

Tags: vba, pdf, powerpoint

I have a presentation of which I want to print specific slides to a single pdf file. Manually printing using "Microsoft print to PDF" gives perfect result.

The presentation however consists of about 72 sheets (36 pairs) I want to print regularly. Presentation contains set of 2 sheets of drawings per sample I want to create a document per sample type containing both sheets. Doing this manually is super repetitive, tedious and I am bound to make mistakes.

When I try to print using VBA code using

```
ActivePresentation.ExportAsFixedFormat
```

the result is significantly of poorer quality, very blurry.

Manually printing 2 sheets gives a pdf file of about 1200 kb and the vba of the same 2 sheets Export is just 300 kb.

[image]

[image]

I'm using code that goes somewhat like this:

```
    Sub ExportSlideDuoToIndividualPDF()
    Dim sPath As String, xPath As String, myletters As String
    Dim steps As Integer, j As Integer, i As Integer

    ' Presentation contains set of 2 sheets of drawings per sample type
    ' A pdf document per sample type to be printed containing the sheets
    ' Sample types are depicted with single digit

    myletters = "ABC" 'Just 3 during code testing

    sPath = "C:\Output\Drawings for sample @.pdf"

    steps = Len(myletters)
    j = 1 'Of set counter for tupple
    For i = 1 To steps
        xPath = Replace(sPath, "@", Mid(myletters, i, 1))
        ActivePresentation.Slides.Range(Array(j, j + 1)).Select
        ActivePresentation.ExportAsFixedFormat Path:=xPath, FixedFormatType:=ppFixedFormatTypePDF, RangeType:=ppPrintSelection
        j = j + 2 ' jump to next tupple
    Next i


    End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried supplying an argument for the `Intent` parameter?

Comment: ...or there's a print quality setting under File > options > advanced

Comment: Thank you Tim, the default Intent:=ppFixedFormatIntentSreen proves to be the problem. Adding Intent:=ppFixedFormatIntentPrint solved the problem!

Answer (score 1):

Read the doc
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.presentation.exportasfixedformat#example

and adjust so here changed screen (low quality) to print (your desire)

```
Public Sub ExportAsFixedFormat_Example() 
 
       ActivePresentation.ExportAsFixedFormat "C:\Output\Drawings for sample @.pdf", ppFixedFormatTypePDF, ppFixedFormatIntentPrint, , , ppPrintOutputBuildSlides, , ppPrintSlideRange, , , , , ,  
 
End Sub
```

**Thus using your in loop ? method set intent to Print**

```
    ActivePresentation.ExportAsFixedFormat Path:=xPath, FixedFormatType:=ppFixedFormatTypePDF, ..., Intent:=ppFixedFormatIntentPrint
```

Comment: the default Intent:=ppFixedFormatIntentSreen proves to be the problem. Adding Intent:=ppFixedFormatIntentPrint solved the problem!

Answer (score 0):

the default Intent:=ppFixedFormatIntentSreen proves to be the problem. Adding Intent:=ppFixedFormatIntentPrint solved the problem!

Comment: Add code formatting

Answer (score -1):

Did you try these methods I could figure out?

- [Slide.Export](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.slide.export)
- [SlideRange.Export](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.sliderange.export)
- [Presentation.PrintOut](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.presentation.printout)
- [Presentation.SaveAs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.presentation.saveas)
- [Presentation.SaveCopyAs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.presentation.savecopyas)

> ps. As long as I get your response, I may still be able to add my answer here. It's just a guideline, it doesn't end here. If you can follow my guidelines and do it, doesn't need my help anymore, so why should I repeat them? If you can actually make it on your own, of course, the best, and I do not need to exceed the authority of it. Would you agree?

Comment: If you just want to paste a bunch of links, please do it in a comment. It's not good enough for an answer.

Comment: @JohnKorchok Because this is also the answer to his question ah, and contains links to the content is usually too long to write in the comments. Moreover, as long as I get his response, I may still be able to add my answer. It's just a guideline, it doesn't end here. If he can follow my guidelines and do it, doesn't need my help anymore, so why should I repeat them? If he can actually make it on his own, of course, the best, and I do not need to exceed the authority of it. Don't you agree?

Comment: @KJ You seem to be responding to the wrong post, read your response, you should be responding to the questioner, right? However method **ExportAsFixedFormat** is what he used, not **Export**.